# Get data values in OnChange Select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application.

This is how I add the select in Razor View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.VariableDataList[i].VariableDataForLevel[j].VariableDataId,
    new SelectList(Model.variableDataItems, "Id", "Name",
    Model.VariableDataList[i].VariableDataForLevel[j].VariableDataId),
    new {
        @onchange = "OnChangeVariableDataId(event, " + @i + ", "+ @j + ");",
        data_list_index = @i,
        data_level_index = @j
    })
```

I have this select:

```
<select name="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].VariableDataId" class="valid" id="VariableDataList_0__VariableDataForLevel_0__VariableDataId" aria-invalid="false" onchange="OnChangeVariableDataId(event, 0, 0);" data-list-index="0" data-level-index="0">
[ ... ]
</select>
```

I want to get the value of data fields `data-list-index="0" data-level-index="0"` in `OnChangeVariableDataId` function:

```
function OnChangeVariableDataId(event, levelIndex, vDataIndex) {
    var aux = $(this).id;
    var list = $(this).data('list-index');
    var level = $(this).data('level-index');

[ ... ]
}
```

But `aux`, `list` and `level` variables are `undefined`.

How can I get those values?

Using Visual Studio debugger I have found that on `event.srcElement.dataset` there are two keys `levelIndex` and `listIndex` with their corresponding values. By the way I have also tried with `levelIndex` and `listIndex` in the `$(this).data` getting the same `undefined` value.

Even if I change `OnChangeVariableDataId(even, 0, 0)` with `OnChangeVariableDataId()` I get the same undefined values.

I'm sure the problem is with `$(this)`.

Comment: try use `attr()`

Comment: `$('select').change(function() { var list = $(this).data('list-index'); ... });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, but I can't do that. The view is more complex that you can see in this question. By the way, I've tried to do it what you have suggested me but I get the same `undefined` values.

Comment: No you will not :) And stop polluting your mark up with behavior - use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: how are you setting those data attributes if you set them using `.attr()` you can get them the same way.. same if you set using `.data()` you get it using `data()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke polluting my mark up with behaviour? What do you mean?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't understand you. I'm not sure if you are trying to show me how to do it or saying that I don't know how to do it. I suppose if I ask something is because I don't know how to do it. But I'm not sure what are you trying to say because I'm not English and maybe I'm lost in translation.

Comment: Using `onclick` is outdated practice. Read the link I gave you to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your item to inline function:

```
 onchange="OnChangeVariableDataId(this, 0, 0);"
```

And then you will be able to get your data like this:

```
function OnChangeVariableDataId(select, levelIndex, vDataIndex) {
  var aux = $(select)[0].id;
  var list = $(select).data('list-index');
  var level = $(select).data('level-index');
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z6vfmqL/1/).

Answer (score 0):

try $(this).attr('id')  and  $(this).attr('data-list-index')

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.